# Matlab system of equations solver returns incorrect answers

Tags: matlab

It's not clear how the system of equations solver works. I looked at the documentation and attempted to replicate it to get a solution to a physics problem but got the incorrect answer.

The problem I am trying to solve is a statics physics problem. F1 and F3 are vectors that are pointed up and to the right in the first quadrant. 45 degrees represents the angle from the x axis to F1, and g represents the angle from the x axis to F3.
F2 is a vector pointed down and to the left in the third quadrant. 45 degrees also represents the angle from the x axis to F2.

The problem is to find the values of F3 and g to make the system stable.

after getting the incorrect answer I checked to see if the matlab answer was maybe just a different answer that also solves the system but after checking it didn't work.

```
theta = 45;
F1 = 8;
F2 = 16;

syms F3 g;
eq1 = F1*cosd(theta) + F3*cosd(g) == F2*cosd(theta);
eq1 = F1*sind(theta) + F3*sind(g) == F2*sind(theta);

sol = solve([eq1,eq2],[F3,g]);
double(sol.F3)
double(sol.g)
```

The output was F3 = 45 and g = -135

the answer should be F3 = 8 and g = 45 degrees.

I am certain that the equations that I used are correct because when I put them into desmos and graphed them I got the correct answer. So the problem must have been my syntax in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo here:

```
syms F3 g;
eq1 = F1*cosd(theta) + F3*cosd(g) == F2*cosd(theta);
eq1 = F1*sind(theta) + F3*sind(g) == F2*sind(theta); % HERE
```

The second equation should be `eq2`, not `eq1`.  `eq2` is probably cached from previous computations and you used that instead.

Running this now I get:

```
>> double(sol.F3)

ans =

     8
    -8

>> double(sol.g)

ans =

    45
  -135
```

You can discard the negative solutions as they don't make sense physically, so you do indeed get 8 and 45 as per your expectations.

## Word of advice

Use [`clearvars`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html) in your MATLAB script before you start any work.  It prevents caching problems such as above.

Comment: any reason why clearvars should be used over simple clear?

Comment: @user2305193 [As per MATLAB's documentation on `clear`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#btd0uqt-4), using `clear` which is an alias to `clear all` should not be used just to clear workspace variables. It also clears functions and scripts.  Using `clear all` causes MATLAB to compile previously cached code and can decrease performance.  In addition, more recent versions of MATLAB if you use the MATLAB editor to write MATLAB code will give you a M-Lint warning recommending you do not use `clear all` or `clear`.